# Android animation - only half of image fading

Tags: android, animation, android-relativelayout, fade

I have a few images in a `RelativeLayout`:

[image]

but this is how the images fade:

[image]

When the `fade` is complete, the images return to their normal appearance.
I've been stuck on this for a while, and I do not know what is causing my images to fade like this. I tried using `clearAnimation()` but that did not work. I added `android:fillAfter="true"` in the `xml` with no results...

Can someone please help?

Here is my code:

*Note - `R.id.rl_images` is the `RelativeLayout` the images are stored in.

**Also, I am using `Drag and Drop` to drag these images across the screen. The `fade` bug occurs after I drag the images around. Please let me know if I need to provide code for the `Drag and Drop` method too. I assume the issue is with the `Animation` and not `Drag and Drop`.

```
public void fadeAnimation(View view){
   final Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade);

    findViewById(R.id.logo1).startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
    findViewById(R.id.logo2).startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
    findViewById(R.id.logo3).startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);

    fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            View view = findViewById(R.id.rl_images);

            view.clearAnimation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT** Added code for `Drag and Drop` listener

```
   class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    if(v==findViewById(R.id.buttonId))
                        findViewById(R.id.removeText).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    else
                        if(v==findViewById(R.id.tBar))
                            findViewById(R.id.removeText2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    else if(v==findViewById(R.id.rl_images)){
                            findViewById(R.id.removeText).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            findViewById(R.id.removeText2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    if(v==findViewById(R.id.rl_images)) {
                        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                        float posx = event.getX();
                        float posy = event.getY();
                        ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                        owner.removeView(view);
                        RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;
                        container.addView(view);
                        view.setX(posx);
                        view.setY(posy);
                        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.removeText).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }else {
                        findViewById(R.id.removeText).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        findViewById(R.id.removeText2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    findViewById(R.id.removeText).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.removeText2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

fade.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Drag and Drop isn't using a view animation as well is it?

Comment: I added the code above for drag and drop. It is using a plain View but not an animation as far as I know --- any idea what is causing this flicker?

Comment: I tried the same with simple touch. it turns out if you change the position of the imageview from its original position then the only portion that lies in the original location fades. Did you find any solution?